# what is the maximum data stored on sql server cluster ever?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cluster-computing

What do you think is the maximum database size ever stored on sql server cluster?

Comment: One bajillion kazillabytes!  muah hah ha... </evillaugh>

Comment: What is the question?  Maximum data *what*?  Column value? Database size? Nmber of Freds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complicated, but you should be able to determine an answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

(Not counting failover clusters)
Instances per computer: 50
Databases per instance: 32,767
Database Max Size: 524,272 TB

50 * 32,767 * 524,272 = 858,941,031,200 TB

Basically, ahockley is correct above.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, but I bet eve-online comes close, their MS SQL server data is stored on a pair or ramsans.